# Make edit link on datatable with multiple column values and global search on single/custom column(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How to create an edit link with function having multiple parameter from the data columns returned from ajax.

I read about the render callback but it only gets one column value & I need 2.
I need something like the following pseudo code.

```
"columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": [0,1],
            "data": "0,1",
            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                return `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="edit(${data[0]}, ${data[1]})"></a>`
            }
        } ]
```

As I'm disabling global search on all column except one. I cannot use the above code that use targets property. I don't know how to achieve this, please guide.

**Edit: Complete code**

```
var datatable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
        "ajax": "/get_data/",
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "deferRender": true,

        "columnDefs": [
            { "searchable": false, "targets": [ 0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 ] }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed Edit link on first column, so I followed @Gyrocode.com answer and it works great.

I also wanted to use the global search for searching but only on one column. [Datatable ColumnDef Documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) gave me the clue so I ended up doing as follows.

Here The complete code:

```
var datatable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    "ajax": "/get_data/",
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "deferRender": true,

    "columnDefs": [ 
        {
            "targets": 0,
            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                return '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-edit">Edit</a>';
            }
        },
        { targets: 1, searchable: true },
        { targets: '_all', searchable: false }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access row data using `full` variable, for example `full[0]` or `full[1]`.

However instead of generating links in HTML, I would retrieve row data in a click handler as shown below:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
   "columnDefs": [ 
      {
         "targets": [0, 1],           
         "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            return '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-edit">Edit</a>';
         }
      } 
   ],
   // ... other options ...
});

$('#example').on('click', '.btn-edit', function(){
   // Get row data
   var data = $('#example').DataTable().row($(this).closest('tr')).data();

   edit(data[0], data[1]);
});
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks. But as mentioned in question before, I'm disabling global search on all columns except one column using the `targets` option and `searchable: false`. If I use your code, the search doesn't work as I need. Can you help me on that please?

Comment: Maybe I should let he global search as it is and have column wise search on single column, the way datatable works.

Comment: I Found the solution for what I needed. I'm gonna Post my solution here. Thanks a lot. Without your help I wouldn't have found the solution.